# display word/excel file content in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-word

I'm beginner in `ASP.net MVC4`. And I'm trying to display the content of the word and excel file in my web page.
I wrote this function in the `HomeController`, but it didn't display the content. it only downloaded the file.
how can I preview the file in my webpage?
Thanks

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult downloadFile()
{
  byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("J:\\asp.net\\ViewInformation\\ViewInformation\\Content\\book.xlsx");
  return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "book.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: One option - [ASP.NET Document Viewer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Document-Viewer-e7c2a39f)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.

```
excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
```

Then access cells like so:

```
int newId = Convert.ToInt32(values[i, GetColumnPosition(newIdColumn)]);
int oldId = Convert.ToInt32(values[i, GetColumnPosition(oldIdColumn)]);
```

Where

```
public static int GetColumnPosition(char alpha)
{
  return char.ToUpper(alpha) - 64;
}
```

and

```
private const char oldIdColumn = 'F';
private const char newIdColumn = 'A';
```

Some resources:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx